# The folders on my Seagate backup hardrives have been changed to shortcuts and no computer I plug them into can access the files

Tags: windows-8, external-hard-drive, shortcuts

While using my Seagate backup hard drives, my Webroot anti-virus detected and cleaned some type of computer malware I encountered.  Afterward the folders on the external hard drives have been changed to shortcuts and no computer I plug them into can access the files.

I get a message stating
 `Windows cannot find F:\Recycler\0xFFD12566.exe make sure you typed in the name correctly, and then try again.`
I haven't typed anything in.  Just clicking on the icons.

How do I get to my data? I can see the drives still have something on them.

The shortcut properties show the target as this - `%windir%\system32\cmd.exe /c "start %cd%RECYCLER\0xFFD12566.exe &&%windir%\Seagate Sync`

Answer (score 1):

What the virus did was hide all your files and replace them with equivalently-named shortcuts to the virus.

Go to Control Panel > Folder Options > enable Show Hidden Files & Folders, and Show System Files. Your files should still be there on your external drive.

Comment: I am using windows "Hate" 8 and I can only find the "show hidden files and folders" option on the c drive. I un-hid files, still getting same error message.  I found this post below but I do not know how to get to the root directory of the external hard drive.  Nor can I seem to get to folder options on the external.               Can anyone elaborate on this: the data must be in a hidden folder in the root directory of the external hard drive.
•delete the "autorun.inf" file the virus created, and anything else hidden in the root you recognize as having been created by the virus.

Comment: Did  this and folders have reappeared but they are hidden and when I go to folder options I cannot un hide them.  the check box is grayed out.                                                          Here's how to view hidden files and system files:

  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/8b0PB.png